# Как вызвать функцию с strcmp

Tags: c++, функции, char

Задача перегрузить функцию, которая будет сортировать строки двумерного массива символов в алфавитном порядке. Пробую запустить код с strcmp в функции void Sort, не запускается - "Sort: ни одна из 2 перегрузок не может преобразовать все типы аргументов", "отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "Sort", соответствующие списку аргументов". Подсвечено Sort в месте вызова функции. Аргументом функции void Sort указано char** mas, т.к. без этого были подсвечены mas[3], mas[4].

````
void Sort(char** mas, int n, int m)
{
        int k = strcmp(mas[3], mas[4]);
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int const n = 4, m = 6;
char mas2[n][m];
    cout << "Массив символов: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            mas2[i][j] = rand() % 256 + 33;
            cout << mas2[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
cout << Sort(*mas2, n, m);
}```
````

Comment: тип в аргументе указателя на двумерный массив можно сделать так : `void Sort(char mas[][6],` и вызвать `Sort(mas2,` а вы пытаетесь принять указатель на указатель. если оставить как есть тогда создавать массив нужно как в ответе **mazik7512** написано.

Comment: *Аргументом функции void Sort указано char\*\* mas, т.к. без этого были подсвечены mas[3], mas[4].* Всегда потрясает вот это бездумное — ткнуть что угодно, лишь бы компилятор/IDE заткнулся и не говорил, что это ошибка. Не потому, что так правильно, а в глупом детском — если взрослый (читай, компилятор) не заметил ошибки, то и так сойдет!! Примерно как при сломанной ноге нажраться обезболивающих и считать что все, теперь можно бегать...

Comment: AlexGlebe, спасибо. А вы можете сказать, почему нужно писать именно mas[][6], почему не работает к примеру mas[][m] или mas[n][m] или mas[4][6]?

Comment: Harry, кажется, вы приписываете моим действиям что-то своё. "Метод тыка" при хорошем исходе позволяет хотя бы узнать, где ошибка и дает подсказку, какой теории не хватает для понимания. Мне например не понятно, почему функция со swap работает только если указать тип данных "указатель на указатель" в параметрах - char** mas , либо если написать char mas[][6]. Если вы знаете и ответите здесь, то это будет гораздо полезнее. Потому что про char** в моем вопросе упоминалось именно с целью получить объяснение!

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно выделять память под массив динамически

```
int const n = 4, m = 6;
char** mas2 = new char*[m];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    mas2[i] = new char[n];
}
```

В конце не забудьте очистить память после выделения памяти:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    delete[] mas2[i];
}
delete[] mas2;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Т.е. swap работает только с указателями? И при очистке памяти нужно очищать каждую ячейку отдельно в цикле, только потом удалять динамический массив?... Просто написать delete[] mas2 недостаточно?

Comment: @Unomuno насчёт очистки памяти, если это двумерный массив, то да нужно сначала пройтись циклом по всем элементам и освободить память в каждом(вы же до этого выделили память для каждого), а насчёт swap, Я не понял вопроса, причем он здесь вообще?

Comment: опечатка... strcmp должно быть. Почему при добавлении в функцию strcmp требуются именно такие параметры, а другие не работают? Например, в функции со swap достаточно параметров void Sort (char* mas, int n, int m) - такие я задаю обычно для всех функций. Т.е. у меня была мысль, что поскольку для функции strcmp нужно указывать только индекс строки (mas[i], mas[i-1], то обязательно в таком виде mas[][6] должна быть указана длина строки, но для swap тоже указываются только индексы строк двумерного массива, однако подходят другие параметры.

Comment: `void Sort (char* mas, int n, int m)` тут вы будете передавать ссылку на массив символов(строку), а не строк, и функция `swap` будет менять местами не строки, а символы строки.

Comment: ага, вроде понятно) У меня ещё вопрос про динамические массивы. Если динамический массив создается в нагруженной функции и является её возвращаемым значением как строка символов, то нужно ли освобождать память от такого массива и где это делать - внутри этой функции или в int main?

Comment: Память освобождать нужно, если вы очистите память в функции из которой вы его возвращаете, то есть перед `return`, память не будет пригодна для использования, т.к. вы её уже очистили. Так что освобождать ее нужно после того как она вам больше не понадобится, в данном случае в функции `main`

Comment: спасибо за разъяснения, стало понятнее. но, кстати, динамический массив из нагруженной функции не удалось удалить в main, т.к. его там не нашлось, видимо удалился как-то сам...

Comment: Из функции нужно возвращать указатель на массив, и потом удалять этот указатель